# How do I fix my SQL related login form strange error?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

I have built a Registration form and a Login form, suddenly for some reason my Registration form works completely fine, yet my Login form only logs in for the first 5 members in my sql table. for the others, it says the username is false.

I'm on visual studio 2015, tried to restart, save, change the database, put in a false password and went through each one of the members in my database.

LOGINPAGE.ASPX:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
 <form id="form2" runat="server" action="Logis.aspx" method="get" >
 <h2> <font face="Arial"></font></h2>
 Username: <input id="Text2" type="text" name="usernameLog"/><br /> 
 Password: <input id="Password2" type="password" name="passwordLog"/><br /> 
 <input id="Submit2" type="submit" value="Log in"  /><br />

 <!-- <a href="HomePage.aspx">Back to homepage</a> -->
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

LOGIS.ASPX:

```
public partial class Logis : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        App_Code.DAL dal = new App_Code.DAL();
        string user = Request.QueryString["usernameLog"];
        string pass = Request.QueryString["passwordLog"];
        if (dal.IsExist(user))
        {
            if(dal.IsExistPassword(pass))
            {
                if (dal.IsSame(user, pass))
                {
                    //Response.Write("אתה מחובר");
                    Response.Redirect("RegisHome.aspx");
                }
                else
                    Response.Write("Your password is incorrect");
            }
            else
                Response.Write("This password is incorrect");                      
        }
        else
            Response.Write("Your username is incorrect");


    }
}
```

}

DAL.cs functions:

```
    public bool IsExist(string username)
    {
        string sql = "SELECT COUNT(Username) FROM Users WHERE Username = '" + username + "'";
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();
        int x = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        connection.Close();
        return ((x > 0));
    }
    public bool IsExistPassword(string password)
    {
        string sql = "SELECT COUNT(Password) FROM Users WHERE Password = '" + password + "'";
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();
        int x = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        connection.Close();
        return ((x > 0));
    }
    public bool IsSame(string username, string password)
    {
        string sql = "SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE Username = '" + username + "'";
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();
        string pp = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        connection.Close();
        return (pp == password);
    }
```

I expect it to login when each user is logging in, but it only logs in for the first 5 users.

Comment: I would refrain from telling them whether it's their username or password that is incorrect. If you say their password is incorrect it highlights that they're trying to log-in to a valid user, might be a daft suggestion in this day and age though.

Comment: Please go and read up about SQL injection, your code is very dangerous...

Comment: does Request.QueryString do any form of sanitation?

Comment: Also adding to @DavidG's comment, a stored procedure might be useful.

Comment: @CaptainWibble I would not recommend sprocs any more.

Comment: Also, storing passwords in plain text is evil.

Comment: @DavidG aside from EF, why would that be? Matt no it does not

Comment: Our teacher really didn't explain much, but he wants us to use the SQL in this simple way. It's too late to build/inject a new SQL. I don't care much for storing passwords, because it's a local host website and it's only for our final exam. Also, meanwhile I was looking to simplify the problem - When I register, the username and the password go into the database, that I know for sure. However, when I try logging in/registering again with the same username, the program does not find the username/password in my database. I think some of the classes can't access the table or the user's text.

Comment: your problem is for sure on `connection` - where you have declare that, and probably you have it as static

Comment: I copied it from my teacher, but I will check it out. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I have given up on this website, decided to try open a new one. After an hour of creating a new website, identical to this one, I have finally found the problem. For some reason, during the day I designed all the css stuff, the Data Access Layer action **InsertUser** that was supposed to Insert the user data to the table while registrating, was set to **internal** instead of **public** . For some reason the program did not send an error message saying it couldn't reach the table, yet it decided to ignore the problem. Really simple and annoying mistake, still thank you all for the generous support and help.

EDIT: Guess what, it does not work once again. I did not check it fully, but after some CSS fun I checked it fully and it does not work. I can assure you that if I manually add a user from the Table query, I can log in as him. But still when I register, the user data goes into the table, but I can not log in as him.